# Github push changes that do not affect current repo status

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I am working on a repo that sees a lot of action on a daily basis. What I am working on will require me to spend a few weeks on. Also the changes I'm introducing will in no way interfere with what's already in the repo - this will be a whole separate folder on the base level.
I've created a branch and worked on my stuff in that branch.

Is there any way for me to submit my work without having to pull and merge hundreds of other commits that will happen from other people working on the repo, since my changes will have nothing to do with theirs?

Comment: What's the problem that you're trying to solve? If the changes are unrelated, the merge will be a simple fast-forward that takes milliseconds.

Comment: Not exactly a problem - Just confirming that this is Ok to push my changes with hundreds of other commits, and there's no way to do it otherwise.

Comment: If it's on a separate branch, then you're fine. Just `git push` it, create the pull request. GitHub will tell you and the maintainers if there are any conflicts. Resolve those conflicts, and merge.

Comment: Ok, thank you! could you answer the question so I could close it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the repository's community workflow and maintainers.  Some may ask that you rebase onto or merge with a more recent commit, some may handle it themselves, etc.  But if you submit the pull request, this conversation *should* take place anyways, along with any other necessary modifications.

So, to answer your question: you can always submit a pull request - it is up to the powers that be whether it is accepted.